# Is setting umask to 000 dangerous

Tags: umask

I know that setting `umask` to `000` causes potential security issues. I don't care. I only want to know if something bad happens if I do it as root (`sudo umask 000`), or in `/etc/init.d/rc` script. By something bad, I mean breaking packages or essential parts of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo umask 0000` will fail because `umask` isn’t a program. It’s a shell built-in command that affects the current shell session. No `sudo` is needed or allowed, though `sudo` commands (and other user switching) don’t inherit the current `umask`. To set `sudo` to use a certain `umask`, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22988764/7208029) gives the solution (I modified it to use `0000` instead):

> For the sudo permissions, I executed `sudo visudo` and added the line `Defaults umask = 0000` to the end.

Since the default Ubuntu `umask` is `0002` (except `0022` for `root`), setting it to `0000` will merely no longer block an application from giving write permission to everyone other than the file’s owner or group when creating a new file. The application then doesn’t have to give write permission to others when creating a file, but now it can.

It’s not recommended to set this globally for security reasons (perhaps in `~/.bashrc` instead), but it’s not likely to cause issues other than bad security when badly-written applications don’t set the permissions properly when creating files.